# Hörmander condition with non-smooth $f$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lie-algebras, sobolev-spaces

Hörmander condition

Let $L$ denote the operator
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^k X_i ^2 + X_0,
\end{equation}
where $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are $C^\infty$ vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that Lie Algebra generated by $X_1,\dots,X_k,X_0$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, if $u$ is a distribution such that
\begin{equation}
Lu = f
\end{equation}
and $f\in C^\infty$ in an open set G, then $u$ is $C^\infty$ in $G$.

My question is, what if $f$ is not $C^\infty$? In traditional results for parabolic equation, $f$ is only required to be Hölder continuous for some exponent $\alpha$, then $u$ can be shown to be $C^2$ with $\alpha$ Hölder derivatives. Does the same thing hold here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[${\color{green}{\text{Otis}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{Redding}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{tried}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{a}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{little}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{tenderness,}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{so}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{certainly}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{I}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{can}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{try}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{a}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{little}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU) [${\color{green}{\text{analysis.}}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXmLjbTBcdU)

Hörmander's condition says that if $f$ is in a Sobolev space $H^s$, then under the condition on the vector fields then the solution is in a slightly better space. Take a look at Hörmander's 4 volumes [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-61497-2), [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb138375), [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-49938-1), and [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-00136-9).

Hörmander, Lars. **The analysis of linear partial differential operators. I.** 
Distribution theory and Fourier analysis. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences], 256. *Springer-Verlag, Berlin,* 1983. ix+391 pp.

Hörmander, Lars. **The analysis of linear partial differential operators. II.** Differential operators with constant coefficients. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences], 257. *Springer-Verlag, Berlin,* 1983. viii+391 pp.

Hörmander, Lars. **The analysis of linear partial differential operators. III.** 
Pseudodifferential operators. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences], 274. *Springer-Verlag, Berlin,* 1985. viii+525 pp.

Hörmander, Lars. **The analysis of linear partial differential operators. IV.** Fourier integral operators. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences], 275. *Springer-Verlag, Berlin,* 1985. vii+352 pp.

There are many papers about your problem.

If your vector fields are smooth, the regularities of solution to$$Lu = f$$have been studied by Rothschild and Stein (see Acta Mathematica 137 (1976) [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~lrothsch/Reprints/Hypoelliptic%20differential%20operators%20and%20nilpotnetn%20groups%201976.pdf)) under various assumptions.

Rothschild, Linda Preiss; Stein, E. M. **Hypoelliptic differential operators and nilpotent groups.** *Acta Math.* **137** (1976), no. 3-4, 247–320.

The paper is not easy to read and unfortunately the proof in the general case (when the vector fields $X_0$ is necessary for Hörmander's condition) is just sketched.

For "parabolic" operator generated using Hörmander's vector fields you can also check the following [here](http://www1.mate.polimi.it/~bramanti/pubblica/Shauder-JDE.pdf).

Bramanti, Marco; Brandolini, Luca. **Schauder estimates for parabolic nondivergence operators of Hörmander type.** *J. Differential Equations* 234 (2007), no. 1, 177–245.

Also, I would suggest you the recent paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5116.pdf) and the references therein.

Bramanti, Marco; Zhu, Maochun. **$L^p$ and Schauder estimates for nonvariational operators structured on Hörmander vector fields with drift.** *Anal. PDE* 6 (2013), no. 8, 1793–1855.

Comment: I am sorry but can you please be a bit more specific. This is a bit too much stuff for me look up when I merely want a precise statement of 
"Hörmander's condition says that if ff is in a Sobolev space Hs, then under the condition on the vector fields then the solution is in a slightly better space. "
and a more precise reference.
What you offered me here is way too much stuff for someone not well versed in PDE theory and is not researching in this area.
I was looking at this:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115417/hormanders-bracket-condition-for-the-adjoint-of-an-operator
but this is

Comment: (Assuming $L$ is smooth) Unfortunately that mathoverflow link is not quite what i am looking for.

Comment: @Lost1 Unfortunately I am not a PDE monkey either. I am a robust algebraic geometer gorilla.

Comment: no worries, i already went through some of this. thanks a lot for this.